# Declaring flavor dependencies in multi-module project using gradle DSL

Tags: android, android-productflavors, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Suppose:

- Module **M** (Android Library) has flavors **M1** and **M2**
- Feature Module **F** depends on Module **M**
- App **A** depends on feature module **F** and has flavors **A1** and **A2**
  (different dimension to those in **M**)
- Furthermore, App **A** flavor **A1**
  depends on **M1**, and **A2** depends on **M2**

Is it possible to configure such dependencies in Gradle Kotlin DSL?  Especially considering module **F** does not know anything about **A1** and **A2** flavors.

**EDIT WITH SOME EXTRA INFO**: in my particular case, **M1** and **M2** are only for bringing in specific assets. So **F** does not care about those and so just has a general dependency on **M**.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve your problem with `missingDimensionStrategy`.

Here's the abbreviated scripts:

**module/build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
android {
    flavorDimensions("module-dimension")
    productFlavors {
        create("module1") {
            setDimension("module-dimension")
        }
        create("module2") {
            setDimension("module-dimension")
        }
    }
}
```

**feature/build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
android {
    flavorDimensions("feature-dimension")
    productFlavors {
        create("feature1") {
            setDimension("feature-dimension")
            // Tells gradle to use "module1" flavor of the "module" module for this flavor.
            missingDimensionStrategy("module-dimension", "module1")
        }
        create("feature2") {
            setDimension("feature-dimension")
            missingDimensionStrategy("module-dimension", "module2")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":module"))
}
```

I had to introduce flavors **F1** and **F2** to the **F** module (which I guessed is an android library module). You say that "Feature Module **F** depends on Module **M**", but which flavor of **M**? I guessed that it was same flavor that app depends on. In any case, if you don't provide flavor specific code in the feature module the result is the same.

**app/build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
android {
    flavorDimensions("app-dimension")
    productFlavors {
        create("app1") {
            setDimension("app-dimension")
            missingDimensionStrategy("module-dimension", "module1")
            missingDimensionStrategy("feature-dimension", "feature1")
        }
        create("app2") {
            setDimension("app-dimension")
            missingDimensionStrategy("module-dimension", "module2")
            missingDimensionStrategy("feature-dimension", "feature2")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":module"))
    implementation(project(":feature"))
}
```

If **F** only depends on **M**, then you can simplify this a little by renaming **F**'s flavors and flavor dimension to be the same as the **M** flavors. This way you can avoid having to specify `missingDimensionStrategy` in **F**, and use only one of them instead of two in **A**. That's because when flavors match across modules, the build system resolves the correct flavor automatically.

You'll see that Android Studio automatically selects the correct flavor for **F** and **M** when you change the flavor of **A**.

As you asked, **F** knows nothing about **A1** and **A2**. I hope this answers your question. If not, leave a comment. [Here's a sample project showing this](https://srv-file19.gofile.io/download/Yhux2O/sample.zip).

Comment: Thanks! I've added some additional info to the question. As soon as I add the module flavors, I get this: "Unable to resolve dependency for ':myfeature@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mymodule"

Comment: It looks like I need to specify what you show in `feature/build.gradle.kts` at every level between M and A (F in my example, but about 5 levels in my real life project)

Comment: The best result I've had is to replicate the M1/M2 flavors up the module hierarchy and then apply the missingDimensionStrategy at the top (app) level. This seems to work but in AndroidStudio I get variant selection conflicts because a variant (F2)-specific dependency in F has a dependency on M2 but M1 is selected. In other words, it's complaining about an impossible variant conflict.

Comment: Hmm I see. I've just seen your edit and I think the best solution would be to separate the assets from M into an additional non flavored module, which will be depended upon by both M and F.

Comment: Perhaps, although I can foresee needing to use M dimension in other modules in the future. Conceptually, A1 depends on flavor M1, and A2 & A3 depend on M2. For the assets, at the moment I just specify the source sets in app-level gradle like: `sourceSets.getByName("a1") { assets.srcDir("../mymodule/src/m1/assets") }`

Answer (score 1):

**This way will work in multi-module projects and avoids boilerplate**

create a build gradle file (for example flavor_config.gradle) and define your config for example:

```
android {
    flavorDimensions 'resource_type'
    productFlavors {
        create("flavor1") {
            dimension 'resource_type'
            versionName "$app_version_name - flavor1"
        }
        create("flavor2") {
            dimension 'resource_type'
            versionName "$app_version_name - flavor2"
        }
    }
}
```

and apply this gradle file for every module that you want for example app module or a feature module:

```
apply from: rootProject.file("flavor_config.gradle")
```

after sync project you can access to specific of implementation of each flavor:

```
flavor1Implementation("flavor1Library")
flavor2Implementation("flavor2Library")
```

Answer (score 0):

faced same issue
you need just copy your flavors descriptions from :app gradle to :module gradle and change paths
my files:
app:
[image]

login module:
[image]